# Why we have always two ips as DNS Entry

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, dns-hosting

Why we have two IPs for dns entry like in Google DNS - 
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4

Or as in OpenDNS - 
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220

Also in router settings, it shows always 2 ips for DNS.

Any specific purpose for the same.

Just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Redundancy.

If one fails to respond, the other one will be tried.  Everything in computing should be at least N+1.

Comment: Yeah that's there. But any relation between them. I mean can i use one from google dns and one from opendns to have better effect ?

Comment: You can if you like.  OpenDNS does some strange things on NXDomain, and redirects you to their "helper" page sometimes. (or used to..)